# Magento2: Issue with translate

Tags: magento2, translate

I add to list.pthml:

```
  <tr>
    <th style="width:10%"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('SKU') ?></th> 
    <th style="width:10%"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Image') ?></th>
    <th style="width:10%"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('EAN') ?></th>
    <th style="width:10%"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Brand') ?></th>
    <th style="width:20%"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Product name') ?></th>
    <th style="width:5%"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Size') ?></th>
    <th style="width:5%"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Leadtime') ?></th>
    <th style="width:5%"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('MSRP') ?></th>
    <th style="width:5%"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Price') ?></th>
    <th style="width:5%"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Units') ?></th>
    <th style="width:5%"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('To Add') ?></th>
    <th style="width:10%"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Actions') ?></th>
  </tr>
```

Now i try to translate to PL:

I use translate file from Mageplaza:
I add below code to `vendor/mageplaza/pl_PL.csv`

```
"BRAND","Marka"
"Product name","Nazwa produktu"
"Size","Rozmiar"
"Leadtime","Czas dostawy"
"Price","Cena"
"Units","Ilość"
"To Add","Do dodania"
"Actions","Akcje"
```

Now I ran deploy pl_PL but no result in frontned.

Also I create i18n in my custom template:
app/desing/i18n/pl_PL.csv

Still no result. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try change in your list.phtml

All echo to:

<`?= __('Brand') ?>`

This part __ is important.(sorry just notice you have this)

If it's still not translated , use Magento command to grab all words from your theme and check is it there.

```
bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases
```

This should show, maybe you need in that case use:

```
"Brand", "Marka", module, Magento_Catalog
```

Ref:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html